# TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with creating a table view in UITableViewController. I have tried everything I have found, reuseIdentifier is set correctly, number of rows returns non-zero number and height is set in storyboard. Only the cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called, other table functions runs correctly.

Here is the code:

TableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class CropTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var photos = [Photo]()
var photoAssets = [PHAsset]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photos.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CropTableViewCell

    let photo = photos[indexPath.row]

    cell.photoImageView.image = photo.photo

    return cell
}
}
```

TableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class CropTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `photos` array is empty, so `photos.count` is zero, so `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `0`, so the runtime knows that there are no cells and that there is no need to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.